# SQL request CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES (working in terminal but not via php)

Tags: mysql, syntax, terminal, temp-tables

I used Javascript ajax to call `PHP` to select information from database.

When I copy paste `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` SQL statement directly into terminal `mysql` it works fine

But PHP returns an error with my request...

**Error:**

> success:"false"
>       title:"ERROR"
>       msg:"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE thismonth AS (SELECT ' at line 1"

Comment: i see you said you have root access: can you still double check if you are using root access from php side. also can you post the SQL code?

Comment: Yes i doubled check:
`mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'my_root_password');`

Here is the sql request
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thismonth; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE thismonth AS (SELECT product_id from product); SELECT product_id from thismonth;`

As you know this is not the reale one, but it makes same error :)
The real one is too long for a comment (limited 500 charac) and not very usefull right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally found by my own the answer...
For those who have the same troubles, **just separate each query** like this:

```
mysqli_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thismonth;", $rMysqlLink);
mysqli_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE thismonth AS (SELECT product_id from product);", $rMysqlLink);
mysqli_query("SELECT product_id from thismonth;", $rMysqlLink);
```

And it works, i don't know why php cannot works with all in one, but ok :)

Comment: PHP can. It is just the DEPRECATED mysql functions that can not. I don't know what book or tutorial you are learning from but drop it. Mysql functions are deprecated, they have not been recommended for years as well. Use mysqli and you can use mysqli_multi_query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php which does support multiple queries i one call.